# How to put an image below another image?

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I want to set images below one another like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3tM7.png)

but these images displaying like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwvzo.jpg)

Here is my html code with css. In code, i used columns but problem is not solved. Images is not displaying as i want to display.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/04/54/98/045498ad4b9b3cdd4d780fcfcaf3392a--cake-decorating-fondant-spring-cakes-decorating.jpg" >
    </div>>    
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="http://www.sliceofitaly.com/files/product/full/0415BDDC-justformylove.jpg" >
    </div>    
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmZNLgk07M9ksvjkM8QHxqdFOkxnqFROYgMBu1Q5T-m2jNfrwF" >
    </div>    
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="http://www.fnstatic.co.uk/images/content/recipe/mini-christmas-cakes.jpg" >
    </div>    
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/32/6c/19/326c191b3b4a373d0b73189551b4a693--spider-man-cakes-spiders.jpg" >
    </div>      
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqESHTW7PwOycYQucPrFkEaTPfdsIod7GYqm3fIUNyQUzHGiS0" >
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0KuVORGDRBMrnC4j4oMm-TU_LmU2JZ0KLeDbD49h5Rt97dXTEEg" >
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0KuVORGDRBMrnC4j4oMm-TU_LmU2JZ0KLeDbD49h5Rt97dXTEEg" >
    </div> 
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="http://www.fnstatic.co.uk/images/content/recipe/mini-christmas-cakes.jpg" >
    </div>   
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0KuVORGDRBMrnC4j4oMm-TU_LmU2JZ0KLeDbD49h5Rt97dXTEEg" >
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0KuVORGDRBMrnC4j4oMm-TU_LmU2JZ0KLeDbD49h5Rt97dXTEEg" >
    </div>
</div>
```

css for images

```
 .card-img-top 
 {
  width: 20%;
  height:auto;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
 }
```

Comment: Use columns instead of rows.

Comment: You can see here to get better idea: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: @Hanif and Usman thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the `column-count` attribute on the row-div. Usually it is used to split up big chunks of text into equal columns, but I found it to be working with images aswell!

```css
.row {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 0px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is my demo code, I am using flexBox. see in full mode**

> Set Box `height:auto` so it will automatically set height of all Box

```html
<html>
<style>
html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{
    display: flex;
    background: black;
    margin: 0.5%;
}

#box-1{
    height: 50%;
    width: 32%;
}

#box-2{
    height: 46%;
    width: 32%;
}

#box-3{
    height: 20%;
    width: 33%;
}

#box-4{
    height: 49%;
    width: 33%;
}

#box-5{
    height: 25%;
    width: 33%;
}

#box-6{
    height: 20%;
    width: 33%;
}

#box-7{
    height: 75%;
    width: 33%;
}

p{
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box-1" class="box">
   <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box-2" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-3" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-4" class="box">
   
  </div> 
  <div id="box-5" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-6" class="box">
   
  </div> 
  <div id="box-7" class="box">
   
  </div>  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is example with picture....!**

```html
<html>
<style>
html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

#wrapper{
    min-height: 100vh;
 height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 width:32.3%
}

.box{
    display: flex;
    background: black;
    margin: 0.5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.box img{
 max-height:50%;
 min-height:15%;
 width:100%;
}



p{
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
   <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/04/54/98/045498ad4b9b3cdd4d780fcfcaf3392a--cake-decorating-fondant-spring-cakes-decorating.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
   <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="http://www.sliceofitaly.com/files/product/full/0415BDDC-justformylove.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
   <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmZNLgk07M9ksvjkM8QHxqdFOkxnqFROYgMBu1Q5T-m2jNfrwF" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="http://www.fnstatic.co.uk/images/content/recipe/mini-christmas-cakes.jpg" />
  </div> 
  <div class="box">
   <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/32/6c/19/326c191b3b4a373d0b73189551b4a693--spider-man-cakes-spiders.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
   <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqESHTW7PwOycYQucPrFkEaTPfdsIod7GYqm3fIUNyQUzHGiS0" />
  </div> 
 </div>
 <div id="wrapper">  
  <div class="box">
    <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0KuVORGDRBMrnC4j4oMm-TU_LmU2JZ0KLeDbD49h5Rt97dXTEEg" />
  </div>  
  <div class="box">
   <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/32/6c/19/326c191b3b4a373d0b73189551b4a693--spider-man-cakes-spiders.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
   <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0KuVORGDRBMrnC4j4oMm-TU_LmU2JZ0KLeDbD49h5Rt97dXTEEg" />
  </div>   
 </div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```